# How can I determine which template column was clicked during a gridview selectedindexchanged?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have 2 template columns on my gridview and would like to execute different code for each. How can I determine which template column was clicked? The code below I am using works for one template column but if I have another I dont want this code to fire I would like to execute different code. Thanks

```
Protected Sub GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GridView1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim row As GridViewRow = DirectCast(DirectCast(sender, ImageButton).NamingContainer, GridViewRow)
    DirectCast(row.NamingContainer, GridView).SelectedIndex = row.RowIndex
    Session("ReferenceNumber") = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells(3).Text
    Session("ID") = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells(1).Text
    Response.Redirect("~/frmEditRecord.aspx")
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have a `CommandName` property set for each of the columns?

Comment: Please post your markup for the GridView.

Comment: Yes, I just posted above. The pdf column is the new one

Comment: I dont see a command name property, maybe I can assign in code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make all of the template field columns you want to differentiate in the selected index changed event have an `ImageButton` control, along with a `CommandName` property, then you can do this in your event handler:

```
Protected Sub GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GridView1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim buttonClicked As ImageButton = TryCast(sender, ImageButton)

    If buttonClicked Is Not Nothing Then
        Dim commandName As String = buttonClicked.CommandName

        If commandName = "Delete" Then
            ' Do something with delete button here
        ElseIf commandName = "Edit" Then
            ' Do something with edit button here
        ElseIf commandName = "Pdf" Then
            ' Do something with PDF button here
        End If
    End If

    Dim row As GridViewRow = DirectCast(DirectCast(sender, ImageButton).NamingContainer, GridViewRow)
    DirectCast(row.NamingContainer, GridView).SelectedIndex = row.RowIndex
    Session("ReferenceNumber") = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells(3).Text
    Session("ID") = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells(1).Text
    Response.Redirect("~/frmEditRecord.aspx")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Use CommandName = "select" to templateFields:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
                 <ItemTemplate >
 <asp:ImageButton ID="ImgSelect"  runat="server" CommandName="select"  ImageUrl="~/Imagesedit_icon.jpg" />
```